# SuperScrollorama, what is TweenMax duration for?

Tags: jquery, gsap, superscrollorama

I am trying to use SuperScrollorama in order to implement a small site with parallax.
I have a few questions but I will start with this: what is the `duration` attribute in the TweenMax function used for?

```
controller.addTween(10, TweenMax.to($('#title-line1'), .75 /*** this one ***/, {css:{top: 600}, ease:Quad.easeOut}),200);
```

I know that the attribute is used to set the duration of the animation (in the TweenMax library), but how is it used in SuperScrollorama?
I couldn't find noticeable differences **when the scrollDuration is more than 0**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's the relation between multiple tweens. If you are using multiple tweens with different durations for TweenMax, for example duration `1` and duration `2`, then second tween will happen over twice the number of pixels in relation the the first tween.

Since it's just a relation between tweens, the number doesn't matter. It can be `1` and `2` or `1000` and `2000`. The outcome would be the same.